# How to create unit test project for wcf rest service in Visual Studio 2010 with mocking(open source)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

We have created wcf rest service and as per our new requirement from client, we need to create unit test cases for all methods of service.

I am done with R&D and found that unit testing can be done using some mocking.

Could someone please explain about mocking(open source) with example in Visual Studio 2010. So that we can refer and can create unit test project for the same.

I would be very thankful.

Below is my code for create account and I want to test this method using mocking.

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "CreateAccount", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    public CreateAccountServiceResponse CreateAccount(AuthenticateApplication Application, ApplicationCustomer Customer, CustomerService Service, Option Options)
    {
        Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Elmah.Error(new CustomExceptionDebug("CreateAccount?ApplicationID=" + Application.ApplicationID + "&UserName=" + Application.UserName + "&Password=" + Application.Password + "&FirstName=" + Customer.FirstName + "&LastName=" + Customer.LastName + "&Email=" + Customer.Email + "&CountryISO3=" + Customer.CountryISO3 + "&ServiceType=" + Service.Type + "&Amount=" + Service.Amount + "&CountryISO3=" + Customer.CountryISO3 + "&Telephone=" + Customer.Telephone), null));

        DataAccess.ServiceType objService = new DataAccess.ServiceType();
        ReloadServiceRepository objReload = new ReloadServiceRepository();
        #region Check Authentication of application and user
        int UserId = 0;

        if (!objReload.AuthenticateApplicationUser(Application, out UserId))
        {
            return new CreateAccountServiceResponse { ResultCode = ((int)ServiceResultCode.Error).ToString(), Message = ServiceMessage.InValidUser };
        }
        else
        {
            //objService = objReload.GetServiceTypeData(Application.ApplicationID, Customer.ServiceType);
            objService = objReload.GetServiceTypeData(Application.ApplicationID, Service.Type);
        }
        #endregion

        IAccountRepository _accountRepository = new AccountRepository();
        IBillingRepository _billingRepository = new BillingRepository();
        string sPIN = "";
        string sUniqueUserId = "";
        string sPassword = "";

        try
        {

            // Check if email already exists or not
            // if email already exists then call ReloadUsingPin and send back the response accordingly
            CCRAccount objectCCRAccount = _accountRepository.GetAccountFromEmail(Customer.Email);
            if (objectCCRAccount != null)
            {
                Customer.Account = objectCCRAccount.Account;
                var response = ReloadUsingPIN(Application, Customer, Service, Options);
                if (response != null)
                {
                    return new CreateAccountServiceResponse { ResultCode = response.ResultCode, Message = response.Message, PIN = Customer.Account, ResponseMessage = response.ResponseMessage };
                }
            }

            string sSpecifiedAccount = "", sAgent = "";
            string sMinutes = string.Empty;
            string amount = "";
            sSpecifiedAccount = Customer.Account;// THIS MAY CHANGE IF IT IS FOUND THAT THE EMAIL ALREADY EXISTS
            //Check for Amount passed in param or get from database
            if (objService != null)
            {
                if (objService.Amount != null)
                {
                    amount = objService.Amount.ToString();
                }
            }
            if (amount == string.Empty)
            {
                amount = Service.Amount;
            }

            LMCreditMinute lMinutes = null;
            if (Service.DestinationCountryCode != null)
            {
                lMinutes = _accountRepository.GetCountryInfoByCountryCode(Service.DestinationCountryCode);
                if (lMinutes != null)
                {
                    sMinutes = Convert.ToString(lMinutes.Minutes);
                }
            }



            //' CREATE OR CREDIT ACCOUNT


            while (sUniqueUserId != "*")
            {
                sUniqueUserId = CustomMethods.GeneratePin();
                if (_accountRepository.CheckUniqueUserId(sUniqueUserId))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            var rsAgent = _accountRepository.ExecuteProcedure(Customer.Email);
            if (rsAgent.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    sAgent = rsAgent.Rows[0]["Agent"].ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    sAgent = rsAgent.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                }
            }
            var pass = CustomMethods.GeneratePin();
            sPassword = Customer.FirstName;
            if (Customer.FirstName.Length >= 3)
            {
                sPassword = sPassword.Substring(0, 3);
                sPassword = sPassword + pass.Substring(0, 3);
            }
            else
            {
                sPassword = pass.Substring(0, 6);
            }

            #region Save in Accounts table
            Account objAccount = new Account();
            objAccount.ACCOUNT1 = sPIN;
            objAccount.ENABLE = "X";
            objAccount.CONTACT = Customer.FirstName;
            objAccount.SALES_REP = string.Empty;
            objAccount.SALES_REP3 = (objService != null) ? objService.Sales_Rep3 ?? string.Empty : string.Empty;
            objAccount.ACCOUNT_GROUP = "WEBCC";
            objAccount.OPTIONS = "NB";
            objAccount.CALLBACK_NUMBER = "NCC";
            objAccount.RATE = "RATE";
            objAccount.EXPIRES = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            objAccount.PREPAID = "X";
            if (objService != null)
            {
                if (objService.Starting_Credit != null)
                {
                    objAccount.STARTING_CREDIT = Convert.ToDouble(objService.Starting_Credit);
                }
                if (objService.Credit_Limit != null)
                {
                    objAccount.CREDIT_LIMIT = Convert.ToDouble(objService.Credit_Limit);
                }
                if (objService.Credit != null)
                {
                    objAccount.CREDIT = Convert.ToDouble(objService.Credit);
                }
            }
            _accountRepository.Add(objAccount);
            #endregion

            string body = "An account has been credited (" + sPIN + ") for ****** customer " + Customer.FirstName + " " + Customer.LastName + ".";

            #region Send email
            if (Options.SendEmail)
            {
                MailHelper.SendMail(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReloadServiceMail"].ToString(), "", "", "Account Credited", true, body, null);

                EmailTemplate emailtemplate = _accountRepository.GetTemplate((int)EmailTemplateType.MinutesAdded);
                body = string.Empty;

                body = emailtemplate.Body;
                body = body.Replace("{{FN}}", Customer.FirstName); //-- Replace URL tag from Template
                body = body.Replace("{{USERNAME}}", sAgent); //-- Replace FirstName tag from Template
                body = body.Replace("{{IMG}}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostImgsURL"]);
                body = body.Replace("{{PWD}}", sPassword);
                body = body.Replace("{{MINUTES}}", sMinutes);
                body = body.Replace("{{COUNTRY}}", (lMinutes == null ? string.Empty : lMinutes.CountryName ?? string.Empty));
                MailHelper.SendMail(Customer.Email, "", "", emailtemplate.Subject.Replace("{{MINUTES}}", sMinutes), true, body, null);
            }
            #endregion

            return new CreateAccountServiceResponse { ResultCode = ((int)ServiceResultCode.Success).ToString(), Message = ServiceMessage.AccountCreated, ResponseMessage = sUniqueUserId + "~~~" + sAgent, PIN = sPIN };

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Elmah.Error(new CustomExceptionDebug("CreateAccount: Message=" + ex.Message + "&InnerException" + ex.InnerException), null));
            return new CreateAccountServiceResponse { ResultCode = ((int)ServiceResultCode.Error).ToString(), Message = ServiceMessage.Error101, ResponseMessage = ex.Message };
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? If you just want *any* example about unit testing with mocks in VS, just Google. You'll find enough. Personally I like the combination of NUnit for the tests, NSubstitute for mocking and ReSharper for running the tests. NUnit and NUsbstitute are open source, ReSharper is not.

Comment: I am using VS 2010 in built test project. 
I have one query : Suppose I am creating test method for "CreateAccount" functionality, in that case do new user will be created or mocking will prevent it from execute, if yes,how it can be achieve ?  Please suggest

Comment: The point of mocking (or in this case: "stubbing") would be to avoid that a real account is created in some database. So if you want to unit-test your service, you would *mock* whichever class it uses for data access, e.g. a repository. If you could post the code of your service class, I could try to give you an example.

Comment: Thanks for information, I have added code in my question description. Please have a look. Thank you

Comment: We may need to skip this method "_accountRepository.Add(objAccount);" so that account should not create.
use MOQ dll because I am using the same.

Answer (score 0):

You will have a hard time testing this method as it is. In fact I would recommend to learn more about unit testing and [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) before applying it to this code, unless you have time and motivation to jump right in and learn from your painful mistakes (as I did, when I started with unit testing).

The two gravest issues with your code are from my point of view:

- The method is very long and does many different things. The shorter your code, the easier to test. Try to refactor separate concerns into their own classes (e.g. the e-mail sending code in the end). Then you can mock them in your tests for the current method and test the e-mail sending stuff in isolation.
- You can hardly mock anything at this point, because the method creates all its collaborators itself. In order to mock anything, you have to be able to *inject* it. E.g., instead of creating the `ReloadServiceRepository` you could pass it as a parameter. Then you'd be able to pass a mock in your test, which behaves exactly, as you "told" him before.

I can recommend these books, if you want to learn more:

- [Roy Osherove's 'The Art of Unit Testing'](http://www.amazon.de/Art-Unit-Testing-With-Examples/dp/1933988274)
- [Mark Seemann's Dependency Injection in .Net](http://www.amazon.de/Dependency-Injection-NET-Mark-Seemann/dp/1935182501/ref=sr_1_1?s=books-intl-de&ie=UTF8&qid=1403076886&sr=1-1&keywords=dependency+injection+in+.net)

Take the time to learn some basics, and you will write much better tests faster.